# haml syntax issue - write separate word in tag, no mapping

Tags: haml

I am pretty new to HAML, can any one explain how I can get it to render:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/">
```

It's the "itemscope" thats causing the problem.

I have:

```
%html{ :itemtype => "http://schema.org"}
```

I don't seem to be able to add in "itemscope" anywhere without getting a mapping error.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting an old question, all that was needed was:

```
%html{itemscope: true, itemtype: "http://schema.org"}
```

and that will generate:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it as a boolean and telling it to format html5:

```
engine = Haml::Engine.new '%html{:itemscope => true :itemtype => "http://schema.org"}', :format => :html5
puts engine.render
```

Should render

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
In the end I used :erb as just wrote it out as normal html.